# Why didn’t Teal’c replace his larva with a Tok'ra?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

When SG-1 visit the Tok'ra in [*SG-1*: "Tok'ra"](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tok%27ra,_Part_1), they each (one after another) refuse to host the oldest Tok'ra, whose host is dying.

Teal'c says nothing during the encounter. Why did he not offer to remove his larva and replace it with the dying Tok'ra?

Answer (score 10):

### Selmak is too old to take as a Prim'ta (immature Goa'uld) and Jaffa can't be hosts.

The Jaffa act as incubators for *immature* Goa'uld only. Once they come of age they need to be explanted. Selmak is a *mature* Goa'uld (sorry, Tok'ra) and thus requires a ***host***, not an incubator.

> **BERT:** *Nevermind. The bad guys. You said they got snakes in their heads?*
>
> **JOE:** *Symbiotes, yes.*
>
> **GORDIE:** *And what about the fellows with the ones in their bellies?*
>
> **JOE:** *They're different. **They're called Jaffa. They incubate the symbiotes until they're ready for implantation.***
>
> <sub><sup>[*SG-1*: "Citizen Joe"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/8.15_%22Citizen_Joe%22_Transcript)</sup></sub>

---

According to Carter, Jaffa are incapable of acting as hosts.

> **GRIFF:** *Hold on! How do we know you're not one of them?*
>
> **CARTER:** ***Symbiotes can't blend with a Jaffa.***
>
> <sub><sup>[*SG-1*: "First Ones"](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_First_Ones)</sup></sub>

This is subverted in [*SG-1*: "1969"](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/1969_(episode)) when Teal'c says that he'll eventually be taken over by his (maturing) symbiote, but this can be explained by noting that there's an element of communication during his regular meditation. As the symbiote becomes more mentally mature, it may be able to control his mind without necessarily taking him as a host.

Answer (score 1):

## "I die free"

A mature symbiote must form a close connection between its mind and the mind of its host:

> If I remain on this planet, I will eventually be taken over by my mature symbiote.
>
> <sup>— Teal'c (["1969"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.21_%221969%22_Transcript), SG1 2x21)</sup>

This is the case even when the symbiote is believed to be friendly and is not expected to dominate the host's mind as a Goa'uld, such as when Shaun'auc, a Jaffa, believed that the symbiote in her pouch had converted to the Tok'ra point of view:

> Shaun'auc's symbiote is fully mature. It must take a host within the day, two at most.
>
> <sup>— Teal'c (["Crossroads"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/4.04_%22Crossroads%22_Transcript), SG1 4x04)</sup>

Teal'c, a former slave Jaffa who has pledged to die free...

> Tal shakka mel. I die free.
>
> <sup>— Teal'c (["The Nox"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/1.08_%22The_Nox%22_Transcript), SG1 1x08)</sup>

...is likely unwilling to risk his right to self-determination by joining with a mature symbiote.